# Installing Wireless Drivers on Yoga 11s

Tags: wireless, drivers, kernel

Yoga 11s wifi card drivers are not pre-installed. I have followed numerous instructions online all of which include downloading the same package, unzipping it, making it, sudo make install. A summary is [here.](http://sudomasochism.com/post/55464266362/installing-ubuntu-linux-on-a-lenovo-yoga-11s) Every variation of this method I have used fails with the same two errors. Two "No such file or directory" errors when I try to "make" the code. I have checked to make sure my kernels headers are installed, because someone said they aren't by default. I believe that person is wrong. @chili555 requested lspci -nn, grep 0280, lsb_release -d. They are in that order.

lspci -nn:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller [8086:0166] (rev 09)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller [1180]: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem [8086:0153] (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI Host Controller [8086:1e31] (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller [0780]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 [8086:1e3a] (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 [8086:1e2d] (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller [8086:1e20] (rev 04)
00:1d.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 [8086:1e26] (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge [0601]: Intel Corporation QS77 Express Chipset LPC Controller [8086:1e56] (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller [0106]: Intel Corporation 7 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] [8086:1e03] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus [0c05]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller [8086:1e22] (rev 04)
00:1f.6 Signal processing controller [1180]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family Thermal Management Controller [8086:1e24] (rev 04)
```

grep 0280 removes the directory and my user name, but nothing else. I can type and hit enter but as far as I can tell it does nothing.

lsb_release -d gives the output:

Description:     Ubuntu 14.04.01 LTS

lsusb gives the output:

```
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 5986:053d Acer, Inc 
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 0bda:1724 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 2047:0855 Texas Instruments 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 03eb:8814 Atmel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 058f:6387 Alcor Micro Corp. Flash Drive
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Wireless is enabled in the BIOS, and it works in the Windows 8 partition.

Comment: At which stage do you get the "No such file or directory"? Where have you unpacked the downloaded zip file? You can use the `ls` command to varify you are in the correct directory.

Comment: Are you quite certain you have the exact same wireless device and need the same driver? Please edit your question to add the results of: lspci -nn | grep 0280 and also: lsb_release -d Thanks.

Comment: @chili555 just made the edits you requested.

Comment: It is _lsb_release -d_ all as one command. We see no wireless device at all here. Is it possibly attached to an internal USB bus? Please add: lsusb. Is wireless enabled in the BIOS?

Comment: @chili555 just made those edits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is your device:

> ID 0bda:1724 Realtek Semiconductor Corp.

It is covered by the driver 8723au which must be compiled from source. First, verify that you have the prerequisites installed:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-generic
```

You need to verify that both are installed before we proceed. If so, download this file and move it to your desktop: https://github.com/lwfinger/rtl8723au/archive/kernel_version.zip Right-click it and select 'Extract Here.' Now, in the terminal:

```
cd ~/Desktop/rtl8723au-kernel-version
make
sudo make install
sudo modprobe 8723au
```

Please post any errors or other snags. I will have another edit.

Comment: Is there any way to do this offline? I have an internet connection on my desktop, and the windows 8 partition, but I don't have an ethernet port, or a plug and play external wifi card

Comment: Revising for off-line.

Comment: Linux headers is installed, but build essentials aren't and I can't run `sudo apt-get build-essentials` because I am offline.

Comment: You can download it here: http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/build-essential Be certain to get all the depndencies; the other packages marked with a red dot. Where applicable, be sure to get the version for your architecture; either 32- or 64-bit. Once you have all the debs on your desktop, you can probably right-click them and install with Ubuntu Software Center.

Comment: Well now when I run sudo dpkg -s build essential I get a thing telling me that the package is unnecessary unless you plan on installing Debian packages which I do. I assume this is the output it should be because it says the same thing when installing via ubuntu software center. However, I still get the make errors.

Comment: That's the expected answer when installing build-essential. Can you please post the make errors here and give me the link? http://paste.ubuntu.com

Comment: [Pastebin Link](http://paste.ubuntu.com/8001853/)

Comment: Please confirm that build-essential is properly installed: sudo dpkg -s build-essential | grep Status. Also confirm: uname -r Thanks.

Comment: I am going out of the country for the next week and a half. If I post on this question again, can you answer?

Comment: I will be happy to answer at any time.

Comment: Now, whenever I start up in Ubuntu, I get an error in the top bar telling me to run apt-get in the terminal or launch a program from the "right click menu." It says there are dependency issues, but whenever I try to install the packages that didn't install, it says they require dependencies in turn, which I don't have. I'm really lost, may have to re-install just so I don't end up installing the same thing twice.

Comment: Does this help? http://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies

Comment: Top Bar Error:

`An error occurred, please run Package Manager from the right-click menu or apt-get in a terminal to see what is wrong. The error message was: ' Error: BrokenCount > 0'. This usually means that your installed packages have unmet dependencies.`

Comment: Make error:
make ARCH= CROSS_COMPILE= -C /lib/modules/3.13.0-32-generic/build M=/home/gabriel/Desktop/rtl8723au-kernel_version  modules
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-32-generic'
Makefile:326: /scripts/Kbuild.include: No such file or directory
Makefile:592: /arch//Makefile: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: /scripts/gcc-goto.sh: No such file or directory
ï¿½ï¿½ÄŽï¿½Makefile:1286: *** target pattern contains no `%'.  Stop.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-32-generic'
make: *** [modules] Error 2

Comment: Did you confirm that _build-essential_ is properly installed as I suggested above?

Comment: Build Essentail returns: `Status: install ok unpacked`
Uname -r returns: `3.13.0-32-generic`

Comment: "unpacked" means: The basic files have been unpacked (and are listed in /var/lib/dpkg/info/[package].list. There are config files present, but the postinst script has _NOT_ been run. So, no, it isn't correctly installed. Please try: sudo apt-get install --reinstall build-essential

Comment: It tells me it can't be downloaded, and to run sudo apt-get -f install because g++ depends on g++-4.8 but is not installable. Should I?

Comment: Yes, please. Let us know any errors or warnings.

Comment: warning: it says it will remove build essential g++ libc6-dev. After this operation, 12.5 MB disk space will be freed. Then asks Y/N for the operation. Proceed?

Comment: Yes, please. Let us know any errors or warnings. Then try again: sudo apt-get install --reinstall build-essential

Comment: Done. Error "Package 'build-essential' has no installation candidate." I am not connected to the internet. Does this matter? If so, I can install build-essential from the .deb you directed me to earlier.

Comment: It does matter! You should connect if at all possible. You can use the version I linked earlier; just be sure to also get _all_ the dependencies.

Comment: Make says it needs the libc6 dependency. On the main page, there is libc6-dev. If I install that one first before make, will I still need make's dependency? Also, does installation order matter for any of these? Do I need all the dependencies of the dependencies? Because that is ALOT of files.

Comment: Order should not matter, in fact you can install all at once. Assuming the deb files are on the desktop: cd ~/Desktop && sudo dpkg -i *.deb. I would get both libc6 and libc6-dev in the group.

Comment: Do I need the dependencies of the dependencies?

Comment: Yes. You should check if they already installed: sudo dpkg -s <some_package>. Be careful and methodical and you can do it. It may take a couple of tries but be patient. Fingers crossed!

Comment: Does it matter if I install the same package multiple times? If one of the packages from the main page are already installed, do I need to install their dependencies if they say they are installed and working?

Comment: Well, I installed all the .deb files. Took some tweaking, but I don't have any more unmet dependencies (I think). Build-Essential returns install ok installed. No top bar errors on startup. However, I'm still encountering the exact same errors when I try to make the wireless driver.

Comment: `Makefile:326: /scripts/Kbuild.include: No such file or directory` and `Makefile:592 /arch/Makefile: No such file or directory`

Comment: We're getting there! Now check to see if linux-headers is installed correctly: sudo dpkg -s linux-headers-$(uname -r). /scripts/Kbuild.include is a part of linux-headers.

Comment: Install ok installed as well. I checked earlier

Comment: Please do: sudo updatedb. It takes a while, so please be patient. Then: locate Kbuild.include. You should see something like: /usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-32-generic/scripts/Kbuild.include. That should match your running kernel version; above, you said: 3.13.0-32-generic. Is that what you see?

Comment: Sudo updatedb doesn't return anything.....

Comment: That's fine, 'no response' means that the command was executed as requested with no errors or warnings. Please proceed.

Comment: First it says usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-32/scripts/Kbuild.include then it says the same with generic in the line beneath it

Comment: Please try this file instead: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/58267392/rtl8723au.zip

Comment: This makefile has the same errors at the same step.

Comment: Hello...? @chili55

Comment: Frankly, I have no clue as to what the error `Makefile:326: /scripts/Kbuild.include: No such file or directory and Makefile:592 /arch/Makefile: No such file or directory` is telling us. The file compiles correctly, albeit with a warning or two, on my 3.13.0-34 system. I suggest you ask a new question with that in the title to see if we can overcome that hurdle.

Comment: Alright, well, I'll do that. I'll mark your answer as correct, because you've helped so much with this. Thanks for all your time :)

Comment: The new question can be found [here.]*(http://askubuntu.com/questions/514463/errors-makefile326-and-makefile592-are-failing-to-find-kbuild-include-and-arc)